# Hibernate query for two tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am new to hibernate so I am pretty sure that some of you would be amused by this question. It has been driving me crazy. This is a hibernate query question.

I have two tables, Assuming one is outlet and one is flyers

- outlet  - outlet name,outlet address, merchantName
- flyers - flyerId, flyerName, merchantName

so flyers belong to a merchant and a merchant has many outlets etc,

using hibernate, to get a simple query like to get the different outlets from the outlet table using the merchantName, I use the code:

```
public List<Outlet> getDealOutlet(@PathParam("merchant") String merchant) {

some code here....

outletsList = session.createQuery("from Outlet as outlet where outlet.merchantName =      :merchant").setString( "merchant", merchant ).list(); 

some code here 

}
```

And that works.

My question is how do I return the lists of outlets for a particular flyerId.

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the question "How can I return the list of outlets for the merchant associated with a particular flyerId?"

If so, do you have a table merchants that's mapped to a class Merchant?  That's the path to go down; Hibernate can easily let you query across joins, but if Hibernate doesn't know about the join because all you've got is a magic String called `merchantName` that you know happens to be the same in the two tables, then Hibernate can't help you out.

(Though of course you could run two queries, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.)

Comment: You'd need to declare a Merchant class (in Java) and then map it (in the .hbm file) to a table that contains the merchants.  Then both Outlet and Flyer (in Java) would have references to their Merchant (Merchant merchant, not String merchantName as you have now), and you would make mappings (in the .hbm) to link them together.

You should read all of these two sections of the Hibernate docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/collections.html.

Comment: Also, [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) is a great book that covers all the complicated nuances of getting Hibernate to work properly.  If you plan to master Hibernate, that's the book to read.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your mappings, if there is an `Merchant` entity, and both other entities have an association to it, it can be written as:

```
select o
  from Outlet o
  join o.merchant m
  join m.flyers f
 where f.id = :flyersId
```

Other wise you can do something like you do in SQL:

```
select o
  from Outlet o, Flyers f
 where o.merchant = f.merchant and f.id = :flyersId
```

Comment: hi amir and Tim, thanks for the suggestions, however, I do require a little more help here.

I do have a Merchant table, however when you  say association between both entities and as Tim mentioned, mapped to a class Merchant, could you give an example, is it in the java class or in the hbm mapping. 

An example would be helpful. Cheers

Comment: Well, you shall go to hibernate docs! Otherwise you won't learn anything at all.